# HTML img alt more than a line of text

Tags: html5

We all know that if an img in HTML cannot be loaded, the alt text will be rendered instead. What if I want the alt be, say, a div? Maybe some JavaScript will help?

Comment: Sure, why not??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alt tag within a DIV but that wouldn't be valid HTML or HTML5.

> [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org)
>
> Attribute alt not allowed on element div at this point.

You can however use `title` in HTML4/5 or `data-` in HTML5 with in DIV and other elements. The rest of your question is not clear and I recommend you edit it before people vote closure on it, also the question may become more suitable on Stack Overflow so please do ensure that you check their for similar questions and answers.

Comment: I think one of us has misunderstood the question. I thought the question is asking about how if an image can't be loaded, the alt tag is shown, but instead of the plain text of the alt tag, is it possible to show an entire div instead?

Comment: Who knows, the way its written is hard to tell...